# Add column to data table whose value is a function of all existing columns

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data table:

```
 require(data.table)
 dt <- data.table(a = LETTERS[c(1:4)], b = LETTERS[10:13])
```

i.e. `dt` is

```
    a b
 1: A J
 2: B K
 3: C L
 4: D M
```

I want to add a column `merge`, so that `dt` becomes this:

```
    a b merge
 1: A J   A J
 2: B K   B K
 3: C L   C L
 4: D M   D M
```

which is a simple function (in this case `paste`) applied to the current row vector. Now, of course I could do

```
 dt[, merge := paste(a, b)]
```

but let's say I don't know the columns in advance -- I just want to use ALL column values as arguments. How would I call my function in that case?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
  dt[, merge:=do.call(paste,.SD)]
  dt
  #   a b merge
  #1: A J   A J
  #2: B K   B K
  #3: C L   C L
  #4: D M   D M
```

Or you could use `Reduce` instead of `do.call`